# Using Nightwatch 1.0.6

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

Has anyone had any luck using Nightwatch-cucumber with the Latest nightwatch v1.0.6.

I have done a fresh npm update. It looks like several of the api that nightwatch used to expose have been moved. 
Is there a plan to update the nightwatch-cucumber to use it any time soon?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber/pull/379) on the nightwatch-cucumber repo:

> From Nightwatch.js version 1.0 you are not able to use nightwatch-cucumber as a full rewrite is needed. That's why was nightwatch-api created.

It seems nightwatch-cucumber won't be supported past nightwatch 1.0

However as mentioned [nightwatch-api](https://nightwatch-api.netlify.com/#what-is-nightwatch-api) has been introduced instead and also supports [cucumber](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-api/tree/master/examples/cucumber)

I successfully ran the cucumber tests given in the example.

Comment: Cheers will give it a try , Was happy to stay at the versions i was but i'm having trouble with the https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1748 bug so looks like its going to be the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **but** Nightwatch 1.0 is still *very* beta as it can flag tests as passed that actually fail. I know nightwatch-cucumber says deprecated, but it is far more stable than its successor at the moment.